# Use class as a float pointer interchangeably

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I wonder if it exists a way to use a class and a float pointer interchangeably. Lets say a class is basically an array of doubles (fixed size). If I have the class pointer, I can use it as a float pointer (easy with the appropriate operator), however, if I have the pointer, I don't know how to automatically use it as a class.

Let me explain a bit more my problem.
I've been using a Matrix4x4 typedef to hold a 4x4 matrix:

`typedef float Matrix4x4[16];`

I have lots of functions that take `Matrix4x4` as a `float*`
Now I'm trying to use a basic class the same way I used to use the Matrix4x4:

```
class Matrix4x4 {
    float matrix[16];
public:
    Matrix4x4();
    float operator[](int i){
        return matrix[i];
    }
    operator float*() const{ // I can pass to functions that take a float*
        return (float*) matrix;
    }
};
```

The problem remains when I need to call a function like this one:

```
bool test(void){
    float H[16];
    // ... process H
    return isIdentidy(         H); // I want the compiler to accept it this way
    return isIdentidy((float*) H); // or this way
}
bool isIdentity(const Matrix4x4 matrix){
    ... (process)
    return ...;
}
```

At the very end, the pointer should be the same right?

(if I declared H as `Matrix4x4 H` instead of `float H[16]`

Is there a way to accomplish this without having to use static_cast or dynamic_cast?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do what you want, but you can do something very similar.

First make a new constructor for Matrix4x4 that accepts a float[16] argument

```
class Matrix4x4 {
    float matrix[16];
public:
    Matrix4x4();
    Matrix4x4(float values[16])
    {
        memcpy(matrix, values, sizeof(float)*16);
    }
    float operator[](int i){
        return matrix[i];
    }
    operator float*() const{
        return (float*) matrix;
    }
};
```

Then you can do

```
bool test(void){
    float H[16];
    // ... process H
    return isIdentidy(Matrix4x4(H));
}
bool isIdentity(const Matrix4x4 matrix){
    ... (process)
    return ...;
}
```

Any changes to the new Matrix4x4 will be lost though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. It is very useful. However I'm quite concerned about speed as I use matrices a lot, so I might stay with the old way using `typeded float Matrix4x4[16]` I would also like to make changes by passing the pointer. I'm sure it is feasible changing the Matrix4x4 class constructor that stores the pointer only but it would get too complicated if I want it to store the data... Anyway, thank you very much!